# pubnup video chat does not working on remote networks

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc, pubnub

Ive checked the questions that before people asked about this but i did not get any right answer.. I have problems pubnub-building-a-webrtc-video-and-voice-chat-application/ . Ive written this code and it works flawlessly on local network, but when i try to connect with a remote client(i.e. not on the same network) the code doesnt work anymore. It just shows a white screen where the video from the client should be (it shows only in circle).

```
(function () {
    var video = document.getElementById('video'),
        vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    Navigator.getMedia =   Navigator.getUserMedia ||
                           Navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                           Navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                           Navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia({
        video: true,
        audio: false
    },function (stream) {
        video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
        video.play()
    }, function (error)
     {

    });


})();

function get_xirsys_servers() {
    var servers;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://service.xirsys.com/getIceServers',
        data: {
            room: 'default',
            application: 'default',
            domain: 'www.thedomainyoucreated.com',
            ident: 'yourxirsysident',
            secret: 'secret-token-from-xirsys-dash',
        },
        success: function(res) {
            res = JSON.parse(res);
            if (!res.e) servers = res.d.iceServers;
        },
        async: false
    });
    return servers;
}

//Request to connect to Remote User
function makeCall( remoteId ){
    if (!window.phone) alert("Login First!");
    else if( !remoteId ) alert("The call id is missing or invalid!");
    else phone.dial( remoteId, get_xirsys_servers() );
}
```

Does anybody know what should i do? Thanks!

Comment: This typically is not a PubNub issue because the "text" messages that are sent over PubNub are likely working. It is probably the video stream that is getting blocked. Maybe due to a firewall. Can you see if your Browser Console shows any errors and report back?

Comment: @CraigConover text messages are not working too.

Comment: Looking at the code, it appears some parts are missing.  Also, Xirsys and other service vendors require a network WAN uplink ( internet connection ).  Running on a closed network should not work.

Comment: We would need to see some PubNub SDK logs to diagnose: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk-troubleshooting-guide - also, open your browser console, run the app and see if there are any errors.